# Inputtext widget for JSF2 will not allow data to be entered by user in XHTML UI

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am converting a JSF1.1 application to JSF2. However I am finding that when I navigate to a new view from the initial view the inputText widgets will not allow any data to be entered from the screen. This problem does not happen with the initial views that are called with an anchor tag or by entering a url into the browser. I am using Wildfly 19.1 Primefaces 7.0 and JSF 2.3. How do I go about debugging this?

Here is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.llts</groupId>
    <artifactId>LingoMavenApps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>LingoMavenApps</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>myMavenRepoLltsRead</id>
            <url>https://mymavenrepo.com/repo/604lAqKzBoKcfngw9N2d/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
            <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>myMavenRepoLltsWrite</id>
            <url>https://mymavenrepo.com/repo/ETqr5l5RKE7x67iZUvi9/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jsf.version>2.3.2</jsf.version>
        <javase.version>1.8</javase.version>
        <javaee-endorsed.version>7.0</javaee-endorsed.version>
        <javaee.version>8.0</javaee.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.llts</groupId>
            <artifactId>burnsiderest</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${javase.version}</source>
                    <target>${javase.version}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${javaee-endorsed.version}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.6</version>
               <executions>
                  <execution>
                     <id>copy-resources</id>
                     <phase>validate</phase>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/LingoMavenApps/resources
                           </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>          
                           <resource>
                              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                              <filtering>true</filtering>
                           </resource>
                        </resources>              
                     </configuration>            
                  </execution>
               </executions>
            </plugin>            
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is  One of the UI views, client.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- 
    Document   : client
    Created on : Mar 9, 2020, 5:49:08 PM
    Author     : mphoenix
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/burnsideweb.css" />
        <title>JSF Page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
            <p:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="true" id="msgs">
                <p:autoUpdate />
            </p:messages>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="tableComp" >
                <h:outputText value="Client Creator" styleClass="title"/>
                <h:outputText style="width: 30px" />
                <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"  prependId="false">
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="ccXmlUploader">
                        <h:outputText value="Load XML File" style="font-size: 10pt;"/>
                        <br/>
                        <p:fileUpload update="process" auto="true" style="width:500px;"
                                fileUploadListener="#{clientCreator.handleUpload}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml)$/" />
                        <br/>
                        <h:commandButton value="Apply" type="submit" action="#{clientCreator.processClientFile}"
                                         disabled="#{clientCreator.processDisabled}"
                                         id="process" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p/>
            <p:dialog
                widgetVar="statusDialog"
                modal="true"
                draggable="false"
                resizable="false"
                showHeader="false"
                position="center top+150"
                closable="false"
                style="padding: 20px;">  
                <h:outputText value="Processing... patience please."
                                   style="padding-right:15px;" />
                <p/>
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="spinning-wait-icons/wait30trans.gif" width="50"/>  
            </p:dialog>   
            <h:form id="clientCreatorForm" >
                <h:panelGroup id="warning">
                    <h:outputText value="WARNING: #{clientCreator.specialInstructions}" styleClass="warning" rendered="#{not empty clientCreator.specialInstructions}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="#{clientCreator.xmlMsgs}"/>
                <h:panelGrid id="op" columns="1">
                    <h:outputText style="height: 20px" />
                    <h:outputText value="Company Information" styleClass="subTitle" />
                    <h:outputText style="height: 10px" />
                    <h:panelGrid id="company" columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Select Company:" styleClass="required"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{clientCreator.clientCompanyName}" style="width: 400px" >
                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" 
                                    update="footerPanel, msgs, entitydependencies, entityselect, client, warning"   
                                    listener="#{clientCreator.companyCheck}" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{clientCreator.companyItemsAvailable}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:outputText style="height: 20px" />
                    <p:commandButton id="companyButton" value="Add New Company" rendered="#{menubean.companyCreatorAuthorized}"
                                       action="#{clientCreator.goToCompanyCreator}" />
                    <h:outputText style="height: 20px" />
                    <h:outputText value="Client Information" styleClass="subTitle" />
                    <h:outputText style="height: 10px" />
                    <h:panelGrid id="client" columns="5" >
                        <h:outputText value="First Name:" styleClass="required"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.firstName}" >
                            <p:ajax listener="#{clientCreator.requiredInputTest}" 
                                         event="keyup" 
                                         update="footerPanel" />
                        </p:inputText>
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="Last Name:" styleClass="required" />
                        <p:inputText  value="#{clientCreator.client.lastName}" >
                            <p:ajax listener="#{clientCreator.requiredInputTest}"
                                         event="keyup"
                                         update="footerPanel" />
                        </p:inputText>
                        <h:outputText value="E-mail(x@y.z):" styleClass="required" 
                                      rendered="#{!clientCreator.noValidEmail}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="No Valid Email" rendered="#{clientCreator.noValidEmail}"/>
                        <p:inputText id="ClientEmail" value="#{clientCreator.client.email}" disabled="#{clientCreator.noValidEmail}">
                            <p:ajax listener="#{clientCreator.requiredInputTest}"
                                         event="keyup"
                                         update="footerPanel" />
                        </p:inputText>
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="Job Title:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.title}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Address:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.address}" />
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="Address2:" />
                        <h:inputText id="clientaddr2" value="#{clientCreator.client.address2}" />
                        <h:outputText value="City:" />
                        <h:inputText id="clientcity" value="#{clientCreator.client.city}" />
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="State:" />
                        <h:inputText id="clientstate" value="#{clientCreator.client.state}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Postal Code:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.postalCode}" />
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="Country:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.country}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Phone:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.phone}" size="40" />
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="Ext:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.phoneExt}" size="40" />
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <h:outputText value="Client PO Number:" rendered="#{clientCreator.clientPONumber eq ''}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <h:inputText id="po" value="#{clientCreator.clientPONumber}" rendered="#{clientCreator.clientPONumber eq ''}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="Client Custom ID 1:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.clientID1}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Client Custom ID 2:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.clientID2}" />
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="Client Custom ID 3:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.clientID3}" />
                        <h:panelGroup id="entprojlabel" >
                            <h:outputText value="Legal Entity:" styleClass="required" rendered="#{clientCreator.userSpecificEntity}"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup id="entprojlist">
                           <p:selectOneMenu id="entityselect" value="#{clientCreator.client.legalEntity}" rendered="#{clientCreator.userSpecificEntity}">
                                <p:ajax listener="#{clientCreator.entityCheck}"
                                             event="itemSelect" 
                                             update="footerPanel, entitydependencies"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{clientCreator.legalEntityItemsAvailable}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText style="width: 40px" />
                        <h:outputText value="No Valid EMail?"/>
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{clientCreator.noValidEmail}">
                            <p:ajax event="change" update="client" />
                        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        <h:outputText value="Username:" styleClass="required"
                                      rendered="#{clientCreator.noValidEmail}"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{clientCreator.fakeEmailUserName}" 
                                     disabled="#{!clientCreator.noValidEmail}"
                                     rendered="#{clientCreator.noValidEmail}">
                            <p:ajax listener="#{clientCreator.requiredInputTest}"
                                         event="keyup"
                                         update="footerPanel" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid id="entitydependencies" columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="LLS Client ID:" 
                                      rendered="#{clientCreator.entitySet and clientCreator.lls and !clientCreator.clientIDSet}"/>
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.llsClientID}"
                                     rendered="#{clientCreator.entitySet and clientCreator.lls and !clientCreator.clientIDSet}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Billing Contact Email:" 
                                      rendered="#{clientCreator.entitySet and !clientCreator.lls and !clientCreator.billingEmailSet}"/>
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.billingEmail}" 
                                     rendered="#{clientCreator.entitySet and !clientCreator.lls and !clientCreator.billingEmailSet}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Special Billing Instructions:" 
                                      rendered="#{clientCreator.entitySet and !clientCreator.lls and !clientCreator.billingInstructionsSet}"/>
                        <h:inputText value="#{clientCreator.client.billingInstructions}" 
                                     rendered="#{clientCreator.entitySet and !clientCreator.lls and !clientCreator.billingInstructionsSet}"/>                       
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:outputText style="height: 20px" />
                    <h:outputText value="Boldface labels mean input is required" styleClass="required"/>
                    <h:outputText style="height: 20px" />
                    <h:panelGrid id="footerPanel" columns="3" >
                        <p:commandButton id="enterbutton" value="Add Client"
                                           action="#{clientCreator.processClient}"
                                           update="footerPanel"
                                           onstart="PF('statusDialog').show('',{top:'100px', left:'400',height:'75px', width:'200px', opacity: '0'})" 
                                           oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()" 
                                           disabled="#{clientCreator.enterDisabled}"/>
                        <p:commandButton id="clearButton" value="Clear" action="#{clientCreator.clear}" />
                        <p:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="Return" action="#{clientCreator.cancel}"
                                           rendered="#{clientCreator.ccClient}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="You are trying to access one of the LLTS custom apps from outside the Dashboard; this is not permitted. Please log into the dashboard at http://pm.llts.com:9090/LingoApps/faces/menu/menulogon.jsp and access the custom app you want from there."  
                          rendered="#{!(menubean.clientCreatorAuthorized)}"/></h1>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here is the method that navigates to the above UI from the managed bean.

```
    public String returnToUserPage() {
        setXmlMsgs("");
        setClientCompanyName(getCompanyName());
        companyCheck();
        getClient().setLegalEntity(getClientCompany().getLegalEntityCompany());
        return "client";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK it turns out that what I needed to do was to use the redirect option when navigating. For example the method above should end in

`return "client?faces-redirect=true"`